# Rotationally Invariance Of Probability Density Functions

Tags: normal-distribution, rotations, density-function, orthogonal-matrices

If $X_1,X_2$ are independent, normally distributed (with common variance) random variables, then the probability density function of the random vector $(X_1,X_2)$ in ${\bf R}^2$ is rotationally invariant.  That means, when $f$ denotes the p.d.f. of $X_i$, we have $f(x_1)f(x_2)=f((Ax)_1)f((Ax)_2)$ for $A\in\text{SO}(2)$ and $x\in{\bf R}^2$.

My questions:

- Are there other p.d.f. on $\bf{R}$ which satisfy this property?
- If some $g$ (not necessarily a p.d.f.) satisfies this, can we deduce then $g(x_1)\dots g(x_n)=g((Ax)_1)\dots g((Ax)_n)$ for $A\in\text{SO}(n)$ and $x\in{\bf R}^n$?

[EDIT] I'm pretty sure the second point is true and this can be shown by rotating a vector along one axis at a time.

Comment: What is an s.n.d. r.v.?

Comment: @zoli standard normally distributed, I changed it in the post.